# Does fuel pump cover need to be sealed with glue?

Tags: leak, fuel-pump

When removing back seats I removed fuel pump cover to check if any water leaked into it.  I had to pry it open as it looked glued down but may just have been the result of time.

When I screwed the cover back on it doesn’t look completely sealed rather there maybe a small gap between the cover and base which may now allow water from leaks to pass in.  If you look closely at the picture you maybe able to see the gap between the cover and base.

Is there a special way this needs to be closed/do I need to use glue etc or can I just leave as is?  If water falls through again could make way into the fuel pump compartment.[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly fine if you leave the cover as is with slightly imperfect sealing. Even if some water would get to it again (which is not an ordinary event itself) the only bad thing it could potentially do is falling through the seal and getting into the fuel pump electrical connection causing it to rust over time. But this scenario is highly unlikely. There's no way that the water makes its way to the fuel pump itself as it's enclosed in the sealed fuel tank.

If you want to be a hundred percent sure you may use a narrow butyl rubber adhesive tape to reseal the cover.

Answer (score 4):

If it was sealed when you opened it up you should seal it when you close it. Automotive manufacturers don't ad unnecessary steps or materials to their car building processes, so I'd trust their judgment.

You want to clean the old sealant off of the cover and rim, then apply a bead of fuel resistant automotive silicone sealant like Hylomar Blue or Loctite 5910 to the lid rim before putting the lid back on and screwing it down. You could also cut a gasket out of a fuel resistant rubber sheet if you wanted, the nice thing about that approach is that you can re-use it if you need to open the tank again.

Comment: This is just the access cover. The fuel pump itself seals the gas tank. This access cover sits under the rear seat. Once you pull the cover, the fuel pump "basket" sits just underneath with its own seal between it and the tank.

Comment: I didn't realize that, I thought it was the tank cover. I still think it should be sealed, so will edit accordingly.

Comment: Yes sealed, but the seal which is attached to the cover is more than adequate to seal out what you don't want in.

Answer (score 0):

This should be sealed with the appropriate sealant. I edited this answer. This cover is for fuel tank access. If it leaks and is severe enough it could potentially allow fumes from a leaking fuel tank or a leaking exhaust system.

Comment: You sorted it, will delete my comment, cheers